# Recover from corrupted REDO files in oracle 12c when DB engine fails to start

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have an Oracle 12.0.1.2.0 (Enterprise package) installation on my Windows 7 development machine. After an unexpected power failure, the Oracle engine fails to start:

Consequently, I am unable to connect with SQLplus to execute any commands and hence, none of the guides I found online to clear the REDO files works for me.

```
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
01033. 00000 -  "ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to log on while Oracle is being started up or shutdown.
*Action:   Wait a few minutes. Then retry the operation.
Vendor code 1033
```

This is the startup log:

```
...
Mon Jun 19 10:56:47 2017
Beginning crash recovery of 1 threads
parallel recovery started with 3 processes
Mon Jun 19 10:56:47 2017
Started redo scan
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_4864.trc (incident=43430):
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00334: archived log: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Incident details in:     C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_43430\orcl_ora_4864_i43430.trc
Sweep [inc][43430]: completed
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_4864.trc  (incident=43431):
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00334: archived log: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Incident details in:     C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_43431\orcl_ora_4864_i43431.trc
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_m000_4680.trc  (incident=43462):
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Incident details in:     C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_43462\orcl_m000_4680_i43462.trc
Mon Jun 19 10:57:06 2017
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20170619105706], requested by (instance=1, osid=4864), summary=[incident=43430].
Mon Jun 19 10:57:07 2017
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_4864.trc:
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017     18:09:53
ORA-00334: archived log: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_m000_4680.trc  (incident=43463):
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Incident details in:     C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_43463\orcl_m000_4680_i43463.trc
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_4864.trc  (incident=43432):
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Incident details in:     C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_43432\orcl_ora_4864_i43432.trc
Mon Jun 19 10:57:07 2017
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20170619105707], requested by (instance=1, osid=4864), summary=[incident=43431].
Mon Jun 19 10:57:08 2017
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20170619105708], requested by (instance=1, osid=4680 (M000)), summary=[incident=43463].
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_4864.trc  (incident=43433):
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Incident details in:     C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_43433\orcl_ora_4864_i43433.trc
Mon Jun 19 10:57:09 2017
Slave encountered ORA-10388 exception during crash recovery
Mon Jun 19 10:57:09 2017
Slave encountered ORA-10388 exception during crash recovery
Mon Jun 19 10:57:09 2017
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20170619105709], requested by (instance=1, osid=4864), summary=[incident=43433].
Mon Jun 19 10:57:09 2017
Slave encountered ORA-10388 exception during crash recovery
Mon Jun 19 10:57:10 2017
Aborting crash recovery due to error 355
Mon Jun 19 10:57:10 2017
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_4864.trc:
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Mon Jun 19 10:57:10 2017
Errors in file C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_ora_4864.trc:
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017     18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
ORA-355 signalled during: alter database open...
```

And here is the trace dump file (orcl_ora_4864.trc):

```
DDE: Problem Key 'ORA 312' was flood controlled (0x1) (no incident)
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
Incident 43432 created, dump file:    C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_43432\orcl_ora_4864_i43432.trc
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'

Incident 43433 created, dump file:    C:\APP\SONORA\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\incident\incdir_43433\orcl_ora_4864_i43433.trc
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'


*** 2017-06-19 10:57:10.590
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
ORA-00355: change numbers out of order
ORA-00353: log corruption near block 37327 change 3289952 time 06/14/2017 18:09:53
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG'
```

Now my question is: Is there a way for me to fix this issue without reinstalling Oracle? I am not concerned with data loss since it is not production data, I just hope to avoid setting up my local databases again since I am on the clock...
Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: Well, I ended up re-installing Oracle.With the engine failing to start, it seems like there is only so much to do. Will leave the question open though as it is unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have another log file in the group? If not...

Mount the database:

```
STARTUP MOUNT;
```

Clear the log file:

```
ALTER DATABASE CLEAR UNARCHIVED LOGFILE 'C:\APP\SONORA\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG';
ALTER DATABASE RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL;
```

Reset logs & open the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
```

If you get a `ORA-01624` during any of this, then a different solution is needed.

You might have to set the hidden parameter `_allow_resetlogs_corruption= true` and/or recreate the control file to recover from this.

Comment: Thanks @Phil for your response. I am unsure how I could run any commands against my database. When I try sqlplus sys as sysdba, I get ORA_12560. Is there any other way?

Comment: is the service running? I hate Oracle on Windows ;P

Comment: The windows service is running. I assume the engine fails to start despite the windows process seemingly starting. The first log I posted in my question is from the file alert_orcl.log, and is dumped while the windows service is starting up.